# Wp_list_pages change page title on output

Tags: wordpress

I am using wp_list_pages to create a submenu on a page and child page.
All working fine

My menu looks like
    `Parent, page title is Hello`
     `Child,` 
     `Child,`
     `Child,`
     `etc`

I am trying to find a way to dynamically change the Page title on output.
In my example above, I would like my Parent page to display GoodBye instead of Hello.

You might wander why I don't just rename my page to Goodbye.
It is because the Page title , in my design, is displayed in 3 different format
- menu Header Hello displays Welcome (can change this via WP menu
- Page title display the correct title, ie Hello

I need my left menu to display Goodbye....

hope this makes sense for somebody

thx

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom field on your page...let's call it `sidebar_title`.

Then, you'll need to convert your `wp_list_pages` code into a custom WordPress loop (there might be a way to use `get_pages` to do the same if you prefer that.

Here's some sidebar code to list the current page and it's child pages, replacing `the_title();` with your `sidebar_title` if it exists. It's pretty ugly...the main point is to show you how to access custom fields.

```
<?php
    //Get children of current page and display with custom fields. 
    //You will probably need to adjust this.
    $args=array(
      'post_parent' => $post->ID,
      'post_type' => 'page',
    );
    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    ?>
    <ul>
    <?php 
        // Print parent with sidebar_title, if it exists
        $sidebar_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar_title', true); 
        if ($sidebar_title != ''){ ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $sidebar_title;?></a></li>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php
      // Print each child page with sidebar_title, if it exists
      while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php 
            $sidebar_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sidebar_title', true); 
            echo $sidebar_title;
            if ($sidebar_title != ''){ ?>
                <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo $sidebar_title;?></a></li>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
       <?php endwhile; } ?>
       </ul>
    <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```